# IPython parallel does not work for me in IPython 2.2 but did in 2.1

Tags: ipython-parallel

the skeleton code of what I do is

```
from IPython import parallel
.....
rcAll = parallel.Client()
all_engines = rcAll[:]
lbvAll = rcAll.load_balanced_view()
....
for anInpt in allInpt:
    lbvAll.apply(mputil.doAll, anInpt)
lbvAll.wait()
lbvAll.get_result()
....
for ijk in range(len(list(lbvAll.results.values()))):
    out = list(lbvAll.results.values())[ijk]
    ionS = out[0]
```

However, all that *out* ever contains is import error messages.
This worked before but but something must have changed between IPython 2.1 and 2.2.  At least, that is my guess.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of:

```
cat /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*.pth
```

Delete the following path if it exits inside the "catted" folder:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages being on the front of sys.path means that there is an easy-install.pth file with this path, which should be removed. It is caused by a bug in setuptools.

If that doesn't work, simply upgrading some of your tools might fix the problem.

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I started the ipcluster in a shell with a different PYTHONPATH than the one I was running the notebook in.  That simple but I took a while.  I apologize for the noise.